# Any Substitute API for Win32API?

Tags: user-interface, winapi, api, replace

I need an API that can make menus like Win32API,
But something simpler and better than WinAPI.
That can make GUI, with text zones, buttons etc...like an average Windows program.(Windows GUI Style)
Can anyone recommand on one like it? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

[wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/):

> wxWidgets lets developers create applications for Win32, Mac OS X, GTK+, X11, Motif, WinCE, and more using one codebase. It can be used from languages such as C++, Python, Perl, and C#/.NET. Unlike other cross-platform toolkits, wxWidgets applications look and feel native. This is because wxWidgets uses the platform's own native controls rather than emulating them. It's also extensive, free, open-source, and mature.

Answer (score 6):

Though I have never used it, QT seems like a pretty decent framework and is open source as well, multiplatform and has a mobile api as well and can be coded with Java or C++.

http://trolltech.com/downloads

Comment: however, while it is open source the licence is only free for GPL-projects. I think this is an important fact to know

Comment: You mean that if I wish to make a commercial program,
The license isn't free anymore?

Comment: There is a Qt Commercial License
http://trolltech.com/products/appdev/licensing/licensing#qt-commercial-license

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at http://www.wxwidgets.org/ - check out some of their [tutorials](http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials.htm) to get a feel for it.

See also

- [GUI Programming APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610/gui-programming-apis#658)
- [What is a good GUI / Widget toolkit for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84057/what-is-a-good-gui-widget-toolkit-for-windows#84805)

(**EDIT**: I wrote this answer in Oct 2008, since then I've become a convert to [Qt](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/) - it makes high-quality cross platform development a *breeze*!)

Comment: Can you give me a good tutorial to start with for wxwidgets?

Answer (score 4):

[GTK](http://www.gtk.org/)!

Though it will require Windows users install a GTK library package in order to use your program (thumbs down on that) its got a beautiful code structure, especially when paired with [Python](http://www.pygtk.org/).

Answer (score 3):

If you really are using Win32 directly, you might try MFC.

Or if you want something more modern, WTL

http://wtl.sourceforge.net/

> Windows Template Library (WTL) is a
>   C++ library for developing Windows
>   applications and UI components. It
>   extends ATL (Active Template Library)
>   and provides a set of classes for
>   controls, dialogs, frame windows, GDI
>   objects, and more.

Answer (score 3):

WinForms and WPF are an alternatives for .NET programming. You won't be able to do everything in the Win32 API, but there is a substantial subset.

Answer (score 3):

Delphi's VCL if you are targeting win32 platform.

Comment: +1 Delphi isn't called RAD Studio for nothing.

Answer (score 3):

1. [SmartWin](http://smartwin.sourceforge.net/) - Win32 Only
2. [Ultimate++](http://www.ultimatepp.org/) - Cross platform
3. [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/) - Cross platform